# How to not count hidden data on RDLC report?

Tags: c#, rdlc

Im currently working on an RDLC file that that shows filtered dealers and accounts. I need to filter data so I used expression to hide some of the data. Once it was hidden, it shows that it still counts those hidden data. How can I only count those data that are only filtered and showed on the report

=This is one of the expressions that i used to count data - "Count(Fields!VSI_NO.Value)"

I tried to use different COUNT expression but still, it reads those hidden data? Any ideas what should i do?